# Vertices not following armature in object mode/pose mode, even though it works fine while weight painting

Tags: armature, vertices

I'm having a strange issue with this spear I'm rigging. I've assigned all the geo to the armature via empty groups and assigned all the geo to a bone. However there are a few verts that refuse to follow the rig in object mode/pose mode, even though in weight paint mode it works fine. [image]

[image]

I've searched for a while and have not found any answers. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There's probably one vertex that has not be assigned to the vertex group, enable the On Cage and Edit Mode options of the Armature modifier and select the vertex that stretches the mesh, then assign it to the correct vertex group, or please share your file

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help! I was able to get it working after fumbling in edit mode for a while.

Comment: Oh ok great then  ;)